# why flutter has stopped to launch my app on ios

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, cocoapods

All of a sudden I cant run my flutter app that uses firebase.

Apparently there's a problem with the pod install process, some dependency incompatibility.
Given the fact that I haven't changed anything in the yaml file and the app worked perfectly this morning, I assume is some problem with the tools and not with my source code.

The problem appeared after a flutter plugin update, but I don't know if the two things are related.

This is the build output:

---

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth

    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (~> 5.19)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Auth, Firebase/Auth (~> 5.19)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:91:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:909:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:907:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:114:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:266:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:174:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:173:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:136:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone XR.