# Error Launching Application - Flutter - iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, macos-catalina

I'm working first time on iOS app with a flutter project which is complete and its android app is already on play store. The problem is I'm unable to run the application in Emulator or Physical device iPhone 6s. I've tried every possible solution in the past three days, none of which have worked so far.

**The commands I've tried in terminal as seen in one of the answers:**

```
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod update
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Although, I've tried other various commands/steps to resolve the problem like `flutter upgrade` but nothing has helped so far.

**The error I get :**

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           21.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.m:5:
    In file included from /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/Private/FLTFirebaseFirestoreUtils.h:11:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:9:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:190:43: warning: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                              ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1: note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg(
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:290:24: warning: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                           ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:219:1: note: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    __deprecated_msg(
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:136:30: warning: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                 ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:283:56: note: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldEstablishDirectChannel DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
                                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:181:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    /Users/ajay/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:191:52: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                       ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:179:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    /Users/ajay/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:289:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:253:1: note: method 'messaging:didReceiveMessage:' declared here
    - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
    ^
    /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-7.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:291:63: warning: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                                  ^
    In module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/ajay/Downloads/aatmanirbhar_pledge_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:72:
    /Users/ajay/Downloads/aatmanirbhar_pledge_flutter-master/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FIRMessaging.h:226:62: note: 'appData' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSDictionary *appData DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
                                                                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ajay/Downloads/aatmanirbhar_pledge_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:179:60: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE'
            #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE        __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                               ^
    7 warnings generated.
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:5:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.14.1+3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.m:5:
    /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:75:10: warning: "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add `Firebase/Analytics` to your Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics.framework to your project to ensure Firebase Messaging works as intended." [-W#warnings]
            #warning "FirebaseAnalytics.framework is not included in your target. Please add \
             ^
    1 warning generated.
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/OptimizationProfiles/Runner.profdata' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master/ios/OptimizationProfiles/Runner.profdata' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dkyjnbdvtzuxypcuezsioswyksyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner_vers.o /Users/ajay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dkyjnbdvtzuxypcuezsioswyksyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/Runner_vers.c normal arm64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'share' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'permissions_plugin' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'permission' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'google_sign_in' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuthInterop' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalyticsInterop' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Ajay’s iPhone.
```

I've configured the Devices and Siginings & Capability section already, I just want to test the application before uploading on app store. I've found a similar unanswered question - [why flutter has stopped to launch my app on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958173/why-flutter-has-stopped-to-launch-my-app-on-ios)

As User Atif told me, the error output of `flutter run --verbose` is

```
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 40,800ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `flutter run --verbose`.

Comment: Are you sure your project is in this path: /Users/user/Downloads/app_flutter-master

Comment: @Akif Yes, the path is correct though. I've edited it for this answer, it was something else.

Comment: @Akif I've added the error output of `flutter run --verbose`.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @IbrahimYildirim No. No solution yet, I left it for iOS, costed us time and money but it was a side project. And whatever solutions I had found on internet, I had implemented everything, none worked.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar, sorry to hear that. I figured out how to fix it yesterday, check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

try to do this steps

Clear all pods and relations to it:

in terminal: cd ios

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf Pods
rm -Rf .symlinks
rm -Rf Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf Flutter/Flutter.podspec
rm Podfile
```

Then

```
flutter run
```

it will install pods automatically (it may take some time at first run, depending on your dependencies).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I think there is another error shown by `flutter run --verbose`, I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

*I was also getting this error when trying to run the project on my iPhone from **Android Studio** or Terminal with `flutter run`*

This solution worked for me:

On the `/ios` folder, I opened the `.xcworkspace` project in **Xcode**, where I cleaned and then run the project with my device as target. It worked on first try and successfully installed the app on my phone.

After the project was build on **Xcode** and running on my iPhone, I could now run the app again straight from **Android Studio** without the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, re-install packages and pods:**

Execute those commands :

```
cd /ios/
flutter clean
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
flutter pub get
pod install --repo-update
```

and run the app again

**Secondly, upgrade your flutter SDK :**

Run those commands:

```
flutter upgrade
```

For me, the upgrade fixed this issue.